# How does a is the size of a list greater than the generator that yields elements of that list?

Tags: python

I wanted to know which would be better to return: a list of elements or a generator which yields each element from that list. After checking the size of each, the generator was much smaller.

```
from sys import getsizeof

my_list = [i for i in range(100)]
my_gen = (i for i in my_list)
print(getsizeof(my_list))  # prints "452"
print(getsizeof(my_gen))  # prints "56"
```

How does the generator take up so much less memory?

Comment: It totally depends on what you are trying to accomplish. `list` objects are significantly different than generator objects. A generator uses less memory because it produces the items on the fly.

Comment: There are several issues. One, the size of list only includes the space set aside for the references to its elements, not the elements themselves. Two, lists pre-allocate space, so you may not actually be using all 452 bytes to actually reference values; adding another element may not increase the size of the list at all. Third, I would not be surprised if the size of the `generator` object does not include the size of the `code` object that actually produces the values.

Comment: thing is, `my_list` is a `list`, and `my_gen` is `generator` object. The comparation is just like a `array` and a `struct` which save `array_start` and `array_end`

Comment: TL;DR Knowing the sizes of the objects has almost no practical value.

Comment: Welcome to SO! The size of the return value is hardly important, as others have said. Consider it an implementation detail that may well change in the next release of Python. Use a generator if it's a better solution to the problem and use a list if it's a better solution to the problem. There's no single rule that applies to all use cases.

Comment: I was always under the impression that size of the thing returned mattered. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As chepner guessed, the size of a generator is not affected by the size of the list.

```
from sys import getsizeof

short_list = [i for i in range(10)]
long_list = [i for i in range(100)]
print(getsizeof(short_list))  # prints '92'
print(getsizeof(long_list))  # prints '452'

gen_short_list = (i for i in short_list)
gen_long_list = (i for i in long_list)
print(getsizeof(gen_short_list))  # prints '56'
print(getsizeof(gen_long_list))  # prints '56'
```

Besides that, the size of the return object does not matter anyways. So, there we go.

Answer (score 0):

Check [Generators documentation](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators). It's a pattern that produces items on the fly. Using the keywords `yield` and `yield from` in Python can handle infinite data structures very well, specifically because of the construction of generators.